# Typo3 4.7.0 update breaks my FE login?

Tags: typo3

I've updated my Typo3 from 4.5.5 to 4.7.0 and I get several deprecated errors:

1. ERROR: Content Element type "login" has no rendering definition!
2. call to undefined error in t3lib_div::view_array
3. fail to include class.t3lib_htmlmail.php
4. The install tool gives me "typo3/ext/ directory not writable" but I've the correct right. I've even allow all?????
5. When I select a CType Element in the BE it give   me this warning: PHP Warning
   PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/typo3_src-4.7.0/t3lib/l10n/parser/class.t3lib_l10n_parser_llphp.php line 95

The solution for 2. is to use the new class t3lib_utility_debug but what is with the other errors?

Edit: 1. http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-english/2011-November/078129.html

Edit 2: The solution for the missing class t3lib_htmlmail is to include another class t3lib_mail_message: require_once(PATH_t3lib .'mail/class.t3lib_mail_message.php');

Comment: Did you perform full update flow (also in the `Install Tool`) of TYPO3 ? Does the deprecated functions become from your own ext or from the repository? Did you update all extensions in the list ?

Comment: I cannot update my Extensions because my "typo3/ext/ directory is not writable" but it is??? I did upgrade database in the install tool to the end. The depcrated function and also the missing t3lib_htmlmail is only in my extension?

Comment: I'm afraid, that you need to resolve the writing problems first, and then update the extensions. BTW there rather should not be any exts in `typo3/ext/`

Comment: Thanks, it's worth to try 4.7.1? What is this error with typo3/ext directory not writeable. My file permissions are okey. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You solved allready: install system extension "felogin"
2. you solved allready: use t3lib_utility_debug
3. check where the error is from. Often it is helpfull to search for that file in typo3conf/temp_*.
4. You could check your filesystem, if your webserver is allowed to write to typo3/ext/. I guess, it is not. But you do not need to. Usually you install extensions to typo3conf/ext/.
5. Update your language files via the extension manager.

Well, i know it is to late now, but for all others wo think about an update: just activate the deprecation log in the isntall toll and fix that problems first!

Comment: Thanks. The file class.t3lib_htmlmail.php was part of Typo3. I need it to send mails. It's deprecated. I can't find it anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Updating from 4.5.X to 4.7.x broke my felogin as well. The reason was that there has been a local extension installation that has been of higher priority than the system one. So if you suffer the same update issue, check for an local installation of felogin in "typo3conf/ext" - and delete it in case it is there. This solved my problem!